# using jquery-2.0.3 in ie8 browser : object doesn't support this property or method

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-8

I used jquery. It work fine in firefox. But when I open it by ie8 get same error :
object dosn't suport this property or method . line 834
I disable this line and find same errors in this lines: 836,3316,...

I make sample code and test ,It not show my alerts never:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
<script type="text/javascript" src="jscripts/jquery-2.0.3.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" >

    var isIE8 = $.browser.msie && +$.browser.version === 8;
var isIE8 = $.browser.msie && +$.browser.version === 8;
if ( isIE8 ) {
alert("ie8");}


alert("test");
...
```

Can everyone help me?
Thank you!

Comment: jq 2.x no more support older browser as IE8

Comment: jQuery 2.x has the same API as jQuery 1.x, but does not support **Internet Explorer 6, 7, or 8**.

Comment: `$.browser` was removed in recent versions of jQuery.

Comment: `$.browser` was *deprecated* in 1.3 (January 2009)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As noted in the comments, jQuery 2.x " does not support Internet Explorer 6, 7, or 8"

From http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.browser/:

> This property was removed in jQuery 1.9 and is available only through the jQuery.migrate plugin. Please try to use feature detection instead.

Answer (score 3):

http://blog.jquery.com/2013/04/18/jquery-2-0-released/

> How 2.0 Changed
>
> Here are some highlights of the changes that jQuery 2.0 brings:
>
> No more support for IE 6/7/8: Remember that this can also affect IE9
>   and even IE10 if they are used in their “Compatibility View” modes
>   that emulate older versions. To prevent these newer IE versions from
>   slipping back into prehistoric modes, we suggest you always use an
>   X-UA-Compatible tag or HTTP header. If you can use the HTTP header it
>   is slightly better for performance because it avoids a potential
>   browser parser restart.